# Adding external jars in EMR Notebooks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I use EMR Notebook connected to EMR cluster. Kernel is Spark and language is Scala. I need some jars that are located in S3 bucket. 
How can I add jars?

In case of 'spark-shell' it's easy:

> spark-shell --jars "s3://some/path/file.jar, s3://some/path/faile2.jar"

Also in scala console I can do

> :require s3://some/path/file.jar

Comment: what is the kernel you are using?

Comment: Kernel is Spark and language is Scala

Comment: did you try AddJar s3://some/path/file.jar ?

Comment: yes, receive error: Incomplete statement

Comment: is there a way to add maven dependency ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you start the notebook, you can do this in a cell:

```
%%configure -f
{
"conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.jsuereth:scala-arm_2.11:2.0,ml.combust.bundle:bundle-ml_2.11:0.13.0,com.databricks:dbutils-api_2.11:0.0.3"},

"jars": [
        "//path to external downloaded jars"
    ],

}
```

Comment: I tried this in such way

%%configure -f
{
"conf": {"spark.jars.packages":"//path to external downloaded jars"}
}

and this

%%configure -f
{
"conf": {"jars":"//path to external downloaded jars"}
}

Comment: Should i use exactly with this line
"conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.jsuereth:scala-arm_2.11:2.0,ml.combust.bundle:bundle-ml_2.11:0.13.0,com.databricks:dbutils-api_2.11:0.0.3"},
?

Comment: Those are just sample jars, that I needed for my notebook. You need to replace the jars, with the jars you need

Comment: Should I use "spark.jars.packages" : "" or "jars": [""] ?

Comment: I used this, some time ago. You need to check this with the current version you are using

Comment: How we can specify maven repository in this? I am using below command to launch pyspark on master node but not able to figure out how to configure repository using %%configure

sudo pyspark --repositories http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1,com.amazon.redshift:redshift-jdbc42:1.2.34.1058

Comment: I am running a Sagmaker notebook instance backed by EMR cluster (via Livy). I am able to use the following method to add my own Scala jar to be used in my notebook `%%configure -f

{
    "jars": [
        "s3://bucket/prefix/package.jar"
    ]
}`

Comment: any ideas how this works in a pyspark kernel (not scala)?

Answer (score 13):

Just put that on your first paragraph:

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        "spark.jars": "s3://YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_DRIVER.jar"
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Remeber to run this before a scala command.

Comment: @IgorTavares EMR v5.29.0 notebook stop complaininig about library not found, but I got strange NullPointerException after adding `spark.jars` which points to S3. I'm afraid stack trace doesn't tell me much, since I'm not sure if EMR stack trace matches the open source Spark code lines.

Comment: I get, "Error parsing magics!: Magic configure does not exist!"

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to automate I'd suggest this:

In your cluster's bootstrap script, copy the jar file from s3 into a readable location, sort of like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 cp s3://path_to_your_file.jar /home/hadoop/
```

then in your cluster's software settings (in [EMR UI on cluster creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html)) set the classpath properties:

```
[
    {
      "Classification": "spark-defaults",
      "Properties": {
        "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/home/hadoop/path_to_your_file.jar",
        "spark.jars": "/home/hadoop/path_to_your_file.jar"
      }
    }
  ]
```

(you can add extra properties here like spark.executor.extraClassPath or    spark.driver.userClassPathFirst)
then launch your cluster and it should be available thru imports.

I had to log into the primary node and run spark-shell to see where the import was located (by typing in `import com.` and pressing tab to auto complete (theres probably an easier way to do this))

then I was able to import and use the class in zeppelin/jupyter